# How to return the token as a value? Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, token

How can I solve this problem? I made a post request to get the token, but when I return it, it returns as undefined, but when I print it, it shows the token OK.

```
function getToken() {

  // The req.query object has the query params that
  // were sent to this route. We want the `code` param
  axios({
    // make a POST request
    method: "post",
    // to the Github authentication API, with the client ID, client secret
    // and request token
    url: ` https://backstage.taboola.com/backstage/oauth/token?client_id=${clientID}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials`,
    // Set the content type header, so that we get the response in JSOn
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    // Once we get the response, extract the access token from
    // the response body
    accessToken = response.data.access_token;
    //console.log(accessToken);
    return(accessToken);
  });
};
```

Comment: read this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp and this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp

Comment: why don't you simply `return response.data?.access_token`?

Comment: and add `return` in front of `axios`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```js
async function getToken() {

  // The req.query object has the query params that
  // were sent to this route. We want the `code` param
  const response = await axios({
    // make a POST request
    method: "post",
    // to the Github authentication API, with the client ID, client secret
    // and request token
    url: ` https://backstage.taboola.com/backstage/oauth/token?client_id=${clientID}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials`,
    // Set the content type header, so that we get the response in JSOn
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
    },
  });
  return response.data.access_token
};

const token = await getToken();
console.log(token)
// more https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp
```

Comment: Does Not work, it still returns "undefined" but when I print the token before returning it still shows the token right

Comment: you mean console.log(response.data.access_token) works?

Comment: @Anees ure using promises wrong way :) you are not even returning anything from getToken() function (the response variable), not to mention that you have removed the original promise from axios; should be more like `return await axios({}).then(...)` or simply `return axios().then()`, even without await as it's a promise itself and you are awaiting for it after in `await getToken();`